# How to search a file for a pattern and get a new file from the match point to end of file?

Tags: perl, unix, sed, file-processing

I need to take a file and find the first occurrence of a literal string pattern as a complete line of the file:

```
Acknowledgments:
```

And then I wish to create a new file from the line of match all the way to the end of the file.

I expect perl is a good way to do this, but I'm not much of a perl person, alternatively maybe sed is a good way?

Please suggest a simple way to reliably accomplish this in Unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do that using sed:

```
sed -n '/^Acknowledgements:$/,$p' input-file > output-file
```

The `-n` option suppresses the printing of the input to the output.  The `/^Acknowledgements:$/,$` part is an address range specification that says to match from the line that matches the regular expression `^Acknowledgements:$` through the end of the file (`$`), and then to print those lines out (`p`) to the output.

If you want the input file and the output file to be the same, you also need to specify the `-i` option to tell sed to edit in-place.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl

Here is a script that should achieve what you're after.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input,  '<', 'inputFile.txt';   # Open handle to input file 
open my $output, '>', 'output.txt';      # Open handle to output file

while (<$input>) {
    
    next if /^Acknowledgments:$/ .. 0;
    
    chomp $_;
    print $output $_,"\n";
}

close $input;
close $output;
```

Below is the equivalent Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^Acknowledgments$/ .. 0' inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: This flip-flop operator is *wicked*.

Comment: Please edit so I can up vote, I accidentally undid and now I can't re-vote up.